# Sequelize not creating join table many-to-many

Tags: many-to-many, sequelize.js

When I start my server, soon after establishing a database connection I do this:

```
var tool = require("./tool"); //created with Sequelize.define()
var requirement = require("./requirement"); //created with Sequelize.define()

tool.belongsToMany(requirement, {through: "toolRequirements"});
requirement.belongsToMany(tool, {through: "toolRequirements"});

tool.sync();
requirement.sync();
```

I expect to see the join table being created, but it's not there. What am I missing?

```
Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `requirements` (`id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL);
Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tools` (`id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, `idCode` VARCHAR(255), `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL);
Executing (default): PRAGMA INDEX_LIST(`requirements`)
Executing (default): PRAGMA INDEX_LIST(`tools`)
```

It says [in the documentation](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/associations/#belongs-to-many-associations) that the table is created for me. I shouldn't have to manually create one myself.

I am using:

- Sequelize v3.23
- [SQLite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite) 3

Comment: I think you should be using `sequelize.sync()` instead to sync all table states rather than synchronizing per table. Have you tried this one?

Comment: @JasonWihardja I have not- no. I'll try and let you know

Comment: Have you solved this? I'm experiencing the same situation.

Comment: I have same issue

Comment: I'm having the same issue.

Comment: @miqueloi please see the answer I've posted. It is what I ended up doing.

Comment: @CoredusK please see the answer I've posted. It is what I ended up doing

Comment: @aec I've also solved it by using the posted answer. Although it feels like a bit of magic. I don't know how the sequelize db instance "knows" all the tables that exist.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems instead of calling `.sync()` on every single model, I should just call `sequelize.sync()` once.

So that makes:

```
var tool = require("./tool"); //created with Sequelize.define()
var requirement = require("./requirement"); //created with Sequelize.define()

tool.belongsToMany(requirement, {through: "toolRequirements"});
requirement.belongsToMany(tool, {through: "toolRequirements"});

sequelize.sync();

//DO NOT tool.sync();
//DO NOT requirement.sync();
```

Here is an example of how I used it in my project: [link](https://bitbucket.org/aecepoglu/aeelit-is-takip/src/034d4a2f959f0a0dd0597aebbb5cb734ecfc440c/src/server/model/index.js?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Really helped me move on :)

Comment: 'welcome (4 years later, haha)